# Як провідмінювати хідля / хідлі?

Tags: відмінювання

Не можу знайти як провідмінювати хідля / хідлі.

> **Хідлі, лів,** *м. мн. Ходули. Паничі учаться на хідлях ходити. Вх. Зн. 76.*
>
> Словарь української мови: в 4-х тт. / За ред. Б. Грінченка. — К., 1907—1909. — Т. 4. — С. 400.

А також прикметник.

Comment: Ви посилаєтеся на словник slovnyk.me, але сам slovnyk.me не є авторитетом (невідомо, хто його укладав). У цій статті він посилається чи то на словник Грінченка, чи то на СУМ-20, але словник Грінченка (здається) не зазначає форми однини, а для СУМ-20 ще не видано томи з літерою Х.

Comment: А який прикметник?

Comment: @Sasha присвійний

Comment: Мені доволі важко уявити прикметник від неістоти («стіл», «двері» абощо). Точніше я можу уявити щось таке, але тоді, мабуть, запитання не про відмінювання прикметника, а про те, як саме його утворити, — я правильно зрозумів?

Comment: @Sasha так, я поки використав *хідлевий*

Comment: Мабуть, має право на життя. (От тільки мені здається, що це радше відносний, а не присвійний, але, може, такий і треба.)

Comment: Екстравагантна думка: а що як однина — «ходель» («дурень» → «ду́рні», «корабель» → «кораблі», «ходель» → «хідлі») або «ходе́ля» (але тут сумніваюся, бо не бачу аналогів з випадінням -е-). Тоді прикметники були б «ходельний» (з -н-) і «хідлевий»* (з -ев-), але не факт, що читач зрозуміє. Ще приклади зі «вставним» -е-: «ясла» (тільки множина) — «ясельний».

Comment: (У попередньому коментарі біля зірочки спочатку була помилка — спочатку замість «хідлевий» було написано «ходелевий» — але я зрозумів, що суфікс -ев- теж, як і множина, спричинятиме випадіння -е- — наприклад, «кораблевий», а не «корабелевий».)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-перше, я поки що не бачу підстав вірити, що в однині це слово має саме форму «хідля»: (авторитетні) словники наводять лише множину, «Генеральний регіонально анотований корпус української мови» і «Google форми слова «хідля» не знають. Цілком можливо, що в однині це слово справді має форму «хідля» (рідковживану, тому не зазначену словниками), але також можливо, що це слово не має форми однини (як-от «двері»), або навіть іноді вживається з якись іншими (неочікуваними) формами однини.

Ураховуючи, що [всі відомі мені словники](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%96) дають форму родового відмінка множини з -ів, можу припустити, що:

- Це слово належить до м'якої групи 1-ї відміни й відмінюється аналогічно до слова «тесля» (див. таблицю в [«Словниках України онлайн» від УМІФ](https://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)) — от тільки в знахідному відмінку множини, звісно, буде -і (а не -ів), бо це неістота (на відміну від «тесля»).
- Це слово належить до м'якої групи 2-ї відміни й відмінюється аналогічно до «корабель», «пароль», «шпиталь» (див. там само).

У будь-якому разі це буде:

| Відмінок | Форма множини |
| --- | --- |
| Називний | хідлі |
| Родовий | хідлів |
| Давальний | хідлям |
| Знахідний | хідлі |
| Орудний | хідлями |
| Місцевий | хідлях |
| Кличний | хідлі |